# Find a similar matrix with some conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can you find a matrix $B$ which is similar to $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & {-1} & {-1}\\ 1 & 2 &1\\ {-1} & {-1} & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ such that $(1,0,1)\in \ker(B)$ and $Im(B)=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3|x-y-2z=0\}$?
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, one can do this. The pertinent observations are that the dimensions of kernel and image of (the linear operator with matrix)$~A$ match those of the specified subspaces (since $A$ has rank$~2$) and that the two have trivial intersection ($\ker A$ is spanned by $(1,-1,1)$, while $\def\Im{\operatorname{Im}}\Im(A)$ is given by the equation $x+y+z=0$ that $(x,y,z)=(1,-1,1)$ does not satisfy), just like the specified subspaces. (If either of these points would fail thee would be no hope of finding such $B$, as these attributes are invariant under similarity.) Now since the kernel and image are complementary subspaces, all you need is to choose bases in $\ker A$ and $\Im(A)$, and map these vectors to bases of the specified subspaces for $\ker(B)$ and $\Im(B)$ respectively. The base change for to that map will transform $A$ into a suitable matrix$~B$.